# Is it Possible to update Dictionary at Runtime(Jamspell-spellchecker)?

Tags: python, dictionary, spell-checking

I am using jamspell spellchecker library.[https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell] 
There i'm using en.tar.gz model file, which is given in readme.txt file. It is a dictionary which is already created while training. I need to update dictionary with new word/sentences while testing/evaluting? Is there anyway to do this? 
FYI, It is kinda question who are all already experience on this spellchecker library?

```
import jamspell
model = jamspell.TSpellCorrector()
if not (model.LoadLangModel("sample.bin")):
    raise Exception('wrong model file:sample.bin')
print(model.GetCandidates(["i","am","vjay"],2))
```

Here, **vjay** is a new word, which is not in the dictionary, and i need to update dictionary with that word

Goal:
when i see a new word,(which is not in the dictionary) then i should update the dictionary with my new word once the word is valid.

Comment: With "dictionary" you are referring to the built-in type `dict` or something else?

Comment: It is a binary file..while training, a text corpus parsed and get each word and its frequency count, and then dumped into a binary file .

Comment: So, your "dictionary" (which is an unfortunate word in Python context) in the code above is `model`?

Comment: Not at all..model is a kind of object. You can refer the above link for more details.

Comment: Where do we see the content and the type of your "dictionary" in your question?

Comment: It could be any type of text corpus that you have trained ..